# Dropped a table and now: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.TipDocuments'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I use Code First Entity Framework for my ASP.NET WebForms Project.

It worked fine until I added a new object that generated a new table in the database. For I don't know what reason the only test row I inserted in my Seed method doubled itself in the database table. Therefore, I dropped the table right from the left Server Explorer panel supposing that at the next Build the table will be recreated. This assumption was false. Obviously, now I have this error issuing.

Are you kind to suggest a way I could recreate my table and also what I should have done to avoid this loss?

This is my Initializer class:

```
public class DocumentDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DocumentContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DocumentContext context)
    {

        GetTipuriDocumente().ForEach(t => context.TipuriDocumente.Add(t));
    }


    private static List<TipDocument> GetTipuriDocumente()
    {
        var tipuriDocumente = new List<TipDocument>
        {
             new TipDocument
             {
                 IDTipDocument = 1,
                 NumeTipDocument = "Cerere",
                 Descriere = "Cerere",
                 TermenRezolvare = 15
             }

        };
        return tipuriDocumente;

    }
}
```

This is my context:

```
public class DocumentContext : DbContext
{
    public DocumentContext() : base("Users")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<TipDocument> TipuriDocumente { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my TipDocument class:

```
public class TipDocument
{
    [Key]
    public int IDTipDocument { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Tip Document")]
    public string NumeTipDocument { get; set; }

    public  string Descriere { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Termen de rezolvare")]
    public int TermenRezolvare { get; set; }
}
```

In my **Global.asax** file I have the following code:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        // Initialize the document database.
        Database.SetInitializer(new DocumentDatabaseInitializer());
    }
}
```

And my **Web.config** has this connection string:

```
    <add name="Users" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Registratura.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Is it like in your EDMX table is present and in DB it is not? If that would be the case then such kind of error will come. Please confirm.

Comment: @GeekyNinja I do not have an .edmx table because I wrote my code for the classes, context and initializer. I added the rest of the code so that it would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

each time when you update db you may also update Entity model by right click on data model and update model from database.